# imagecreatefromstring returns broken image?

Tags: php, png, gd

I'm following [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) for `imagecreatefromstring()`.

It happens when I'm using the image data that I'm working with.  However even when I'm using the the base64 string for the image from the manual (linked above), I still get the same issue.  imagecreatefromstring isn't returning false either.  However, on Safari and Chrome, I just get a broken image.  Here's a screenshot of what it looks like on Chrome.

[image]

Comment: It's probably an internal error happening somewhere in your code. You should share some of what you're doing! Basically your script is likely outputting an error to the browser somewhere, and you're continuing on ignoring those errors and still telling PHP to generate the output as an image (which breaks it). If you put an `exit;` command before your `imagejpeg()` (or similar) function, you should see what's going wrong output to your browser when you open the image generation URL. If you don't, [turn error reporting up](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: right-click that icon, do a "view image". that'll show you exactly what the server's spitting out. you may have some PHP warnings or other output occuring BEFORE the new image is output, which corrupts that output.

Comment: Thank you to the both of you. You are both great. I will answer the question and close the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was a PHP error that was printed right before the createimagefromstring chunk of code was called, thereby breaking the image.  The problem for my code specifically was related ldap_close().